# Align divs with different height

Tags: html, css

What's the best way to align divs on left with different heigh inside a container.

Look like this small:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="height: 20px;">1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div style="height: 20px;">3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div style="height: 20px;">5</div>
    <div style="height: 20px;">6</div>    
</div>
```

It's possible add some css3 code like :nth-child? Because I'm not be able to add a div between the divs, this code are inside a block inside a CMS.

http://jsfiddle.net/andersonfetter/2dWR5/1/

my real situation are in this website: http://www.devcore.com.au:17002/Consultant-Team/

Comment: Your `div`s are all the same height?

Comment: Align how? In the jsfiddle have they same height.

Comment: use `float:left` for the `div`s, and `overflow:auto` for the container

Comment: the number 3 is not under the number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clear:left;` where you height has different and div not aligned in left. i have checked your website and come up with this solution. try once.

[image]

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. I like the divs side by side. Doesn't matter the height.

Comment: See my edited answer. i have applied clear:left and it is now aligned.

Comment: But if I add clear: left on .both I make one column.

Comment: Ok. can you add '<div style="clear:left;"></div>' before 3rd div. if not better make 2 div in each parent div instead of 3 div. this is better it will not create any problem.